# How to join 2 tables in combination with a Relational Table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
customers
phonenumbers
customers_has_phonenumbers

customers -> detailed
customers.customer_id int(11) primary auto_increment
customers.customer_name varchar(255)

phonenumbers -> detailed
phonenumbers.phonenumber_id int(11) primary auto_increment
phonenumbers.phonenumber_type int(11)
phonenumbers.phonenumber_name varchar(255)
phonenumbers.phonenumber varchar(15)

customers_has_phonenumbers -> detailed
customers_has_phonenumbers.customer_id int(11) -> holds customers.customer_id
customers_has_phonenumbers.phonenumber_id int(11) -> holds phonenumbers.phonenumber_id
```

how to get the data by customers.customer_id from phonenumbers?

i hope you guys can help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM phonenumbers,customers,customers_has_phonenumbers
         WHERE customers.custumer_id = customers_has_phonenumers.customer_id
         AND phonenumbers.phonenumber_id = customers_has_phonenumers.phonenumber_id
         AND customers.customer_id = [ID HERE]
```

note: replace the * with the fields you need, for demonstrating only

A better solution might be removing the table in between, but of course this only works if a customer has 1 phone number.